# Using a Function to update SQLite columns DB in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to dynamically update my database. I am calling this function to do so but, the database does not update:

```
def update_stock(data):
    print('Updating Stock Position')
    stock_cursor.execute("""
                UPDATE stock_data SET (
                exited_position,
                p_n_l,
                winning_trade,
                cost,
                sale_price,
                exit_time
            ) WHERE symbol = (?)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?,
                ?, ?, ?)
        """, (data[1],
                data[2],
                data[3],
                data[4],
                data[5],
                data[6],
                data[0],

                ))
    connection.commit()
   
    return
```

I have verified the data but, cannot seem to get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update syntax is incorrect.

```
    stock_cursor.execute("""
            UPDATE stock_data SET (
                exited_position,
                p_n_l,
                winning_trade,
                cost,
                sale_price,
                exit_time
            ) = (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            WHERE symbol = ?
        """, (data[2],
                data[3],
                data[4],
                data[5],
                data[6],
                data[0],
                data[1]
                ))
```